# UNITY ERROR: Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, integer, boolean, mouse

I'm new in Unity. I try to create a project but when I use "<" with two numbers, unity returns this error: "error CS0019: Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'". This is my code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class isDragging : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject playerObj = null;
    private bool mouseDown = false;
    private string chooseNumber = "";
    private float mouseX;
    private float mouseY;

    private void Start()
    {
 object named "Player".
        if (playerObj == null)
            playerObj = GameObject.Find("screen");
        mouseX = Input.mousePosition.x;
        mouseY = Input.mousePosition.y;

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log("Player Position: X = " + playerObj.transform.position.x + " --- Y = " + playerObj.transform.position.y + " --- Z = " +
        playerObj.transform.position.z);
        if (mouseDown == false && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            mouseDown = true;
            float mouseX = Input.mousePosition.x;
            float mouseY = Input.mousePosition.y;
        }
        else
        {
            if (mouseDown)
            {
                if (playerObj.transform.position.x > 727)
                {
                    transform.position = new Vector3(1271.0f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
                    chooseNumber = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    transform.position = new Vector3(178.0f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
                    if (1065 < mouseY < 1265)
                    {
                        if (318 < mouseX < 500)
                            chooseNumber += "1";
                        else if (575 < mouseX < 768)
                            chooseNumber += "2";
                        else if (840 < mouseX < 1018)
                            chooseNumber += "3";
                    }

                    else if (765 < mouseY < 965)
                    {
                        if (318 < mouseX < 500)
                            chooseNumber += "4";
                        else if (575 < mouseX < 768)
                            chooseNumber += "5";
                        else if (840 < mouseX < 1018)
                            chooseNumber += "6";
                    }

                    else if (450 < mouseY < 650)
                    {
                        if (318 < mouseX < 500)
                            chooseNumber += "7";
                        else if (575 < mouseX < 768)
                            chooseNumber += "8";
                        else if (840 < mouseX < 1018)
                            chooseNumber += "9";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Debug.Log(chooseNumber);
    }
}
```

I expected that it returns 2 numbers in string format, but Unity reads mouse position as bool. How can i fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid statement in c#

```
if (1065 < mouseY < 1265)
```

you should use

```
if (1065 < mouseY && mouseY < 1265)
```

The reason it says this is a `bool` and `int` comparison is that the statement is treated as such:

```
if ((1065 < mouseY) < 1265)
```

then the first parentheses is resolved to a `bool` value. Then a second comparison between that `bool` value and 1265 is made which is impossible hence the error you receive.